# How to make continous sequence with javascript

Tags: javascript

```py
def function(foo):
    print(foo)
```

Comment: What is random here stands for? Your desired sequence is absolutely definite.

Comment: Why are you subtracting `0` and adding `0`? That shouldn't have any effect on the calculation. (Anything +0 is that same number.)

Comment: I edited my question. I dont want those number random, i just gave example

Comment: Maybe someone want to explain me why im downvoted ?

Answer (score 5):

```
var number = 1; // sequence starts with this number
setInterval(function(){
        $("#number").append(number);
        number = 1 - number;
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var number = 0;

setInterval(function(){ 
        number = number == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        $("#number").append(number);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
var zeroOneSeq = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    zeroOneSeq ^= 1;
    $("#number").append(zeroOneSeq);
}, 1000);
```

To have the sequence start at 0 instead, initialize `zeroOneSeq` to 1 *or* you can just switch the two lines of code inside the function.